# Division of numbers

Tags: java, numbers, division, integer-division

I could see in Timestamp class, the constructor goes like:

```
    public Timestamp(long time) {
    super((time/1000)*1000);
    ....................
```

What Im not understanding is, what is the need of dividing the time by 1000 and then multiplying again by 1000. What difference will it make? Isn't this piece redundant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a way of truncating to the next lower multiple of 1000 milliseconds -- i.e., to the whole second. It's not necessarily the *best* way, but it's a way.

Comment: "time/1000" piece will round it for sure. However it again multiplies the outcome (i.e. seconds) with 1000 to make it millisecond. (23000/1000) * 1000 will give me again 23000, so where is rounding taking place?

Comment: @Vicky: 23123/1000 = 23, then 23*1000 = 23000. See?

Comment: Worth noting that it doesn't round to the *nearest* 1000 milliseconds. It actually floors it to the nearest smaller 1000 milliseconds. (23999/1000)*1000 == 23000.

Comment: @thasc: Indeed, it's really *truncation*, isn't it. That's what I meant by it being "not the best way". Edited.

Comment: @Ernhest, thasc, thank you very much. i got it. Infact i was even puzzled at the way Timestamp separates the milli and nano seconds. but now i could see that it truncated the milliseconds and rest of the numbers(the one got truncated) makes nanosecond.     public Timestamp(long time) {
 super((time/1000)*1000);
 nanos = (int)((time%1000) * 1000000);